Is the result of pyperf in real time or in CPU seconds?
I would assume the output of pyperf is in real time, but I couldn't find confirmation anywhere.

A simple way to determine this is to get the performance of  time.sleep(10). If it's CPU time, the output will be a fraction of a second, if it's real time it will be 10 seconds.

As suggested by @Barmar, the output of
python3 -m pyperf timeit 'import time; time.sleep(10)' --debug-single-value

is
10.0 sec

This indicates that it is real time.
